# Get range of bits from a varbinary

Tags: sql-server

I appreciate it's a task that's not very well suited to SQL but I'm nonetheless hoping the hive mind can help solve the problem.

I'm looking to get a range of bits from a var binary and I can't find a simple way of doing this in SQL.

```
DECLARE @data AS VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x0102030405060708
```

Is it possible to get 2 bytes back, but starting with the 12th bit?

Comment: `substring` plus some shifting and masking.like `/ 16` and `% 65536`

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want `0x2030` as your result.

```
DECLARE @data AS VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x0102030405060708
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(LEFT(@data, 4) AS BINARY(4)) AS BIGINT)/POWER(2,4) AS BINARY(2))
```

`POWER(2,4)` was derived from shifting 12 bits to the left and then 16 to the right: `* POWER(2/12)/POWER(2/16)` and then truncated with the `CAST(... AS BINARY(2))`. If you don't care about the byte casting, you'll need to logical `&` the result to cut away the leftmost bytes.

```
DECLARE @data AS VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x0102030405060708
SELECT CAST(CAST(LEFT(@data, 4) AS BINARY(4)) AS BIGINT)/POWER(2,4) & 0xFFFF
```