# Deleting tokens shorter than 24 hours in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I develop a newsletter system and generate unique tokens using GUID and the current date:

```cs
    public static string GetUniqueToken()
    {
      byte[] time = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.ToBinary());
      byte[] key = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
      return Convert.ToBase64String(time.Concat(key).ToArray());
    }
```

I also have a function to retrieve this date and find out if it has expired or not (after 24 hours).

```cs
    public static DateTime GetDateFromToken(string token)
    {
      byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(token);
      return DateTime.FromBinary(BitConverter.ToInt64(data, 0));
    }
```

I'd now like to delete expired tokens via a single SQL query, to avoid having to loop through all the lines in C# and run a test each time. What I failed to do

Thanks in advance

I started to develop a piece of SQL code to do this supression work instead of using greedy C# code.
I can't get it to work

```sql
DECLARE @limitDate DATETIME;
SET @limitDate = DATEADD(HOUR, -48, GETDATE());

DELETE FROM newsletter
WHERE DATEADD(SECOND, 
    CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), SUBSTRING(token, 37, 8), 2)) / 10000, '19700101') < @limitDate;
```

Example of token generated:

> Akias1XZ20jFoDOnWSZfRqgFHdv+UUVP

It says:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 6
> Error converting data type nvarchar to varbinary.

Comment: *"I'm on SQL Server 2019"* then please don't tag [[tag:mysql]]; that's a completely different product.

Comment: You need to provide example DDL and DML. It's not clear why you're trying to cast a `[N]VARCHAR` to a `VARBINARY` and then to a `BIGINT`, and ultimately a `DATETIME`.

Comment: Why not store the date _as a date_ in the database (in addition to the token)? That allows you to query it much easier.

Comment: @PatrickHurst he probably stores date as part of the token binary value, because of... reasons

Comment: @OP, you should provide some sample data of how token looks. Otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: There's no benefit to any of these conversions. The reverse conversion can easily fail in C# too, because `ToBinary` encodes both the DateTime Kind (UTC, local, unknown) along with the ticks. The SQL code doesn't even try to reverse the BASE64 conversion. BASE64 isn't needed to store binary data to SQL Server anyway

Comment: DateTime starts from `0001-01-01`, not `1970-01-01`. It's a *lot* easier to store the token as a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column and the time as either `datetimeoffset` or `datetime2` with the precision you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so for some reason you do not store the `date` along with the token. Then, let's take a look on how you compute the token in the first place:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(time.Concat(key).ToArray())
```

That is, you have a base 64 string, which will have its first 64 bits that represent the time. The remainder is uninteresting.

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToBinary()
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tobinary?view=net-7.0

[BASE64_DECODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/base64-decode-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current) will decode your base64 string in SQL Server for you. Now, the result, as per the documentation is

Return types

- Varbinary(8000).
- Varbinary(max) if the input is varchar(max).
- If the input expression is null, the output is null.

Now, you want to [get the range of bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916489/get-range-of-bits-from-a-varbinary) from the varbinary, more precisely the first 64 bits and then you intend to convert that into a date. After converting your value to `bigint`, you can convert the result into `datetime`, see [Convert bigint to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650320/convert-bigint-to-datetime).

Answer (score 1):

The ideal scenario would be to store the expiration date of the tokens in SQL alongside the token (or have a SQL routine capable of extracting the date) so that you can write a procedure (or parameterize a SQL statement) to pass in the date (or hard code the date in the proc), and just do something like

```
delete a
from TokensTable
where ExpirationDate <= @OneDayAgo
```

If that's not possible, and you need C# to do the date extraction so you can then come up with a list of tokens to delete, you have a few options:

### 1. Pass in a delimited list of tokens

Assuming you know a character which you can use as a delimiter (i.e. a character that will never occur in the token strings), you can just using C# `string.Join(myDelimiter, myListOfTokens)` to serialize the tokens, then pass that into the sqlstatement; something like:

```
delete a
from TokensTable a
inner join string_split(@DelimitedTokensList, '|') b
    on a.Token = b.value
```

### 2. Use XML or JSON

Similar in concept, you could serialize the list of tokens as either JSON or XML, then parse them inside of SQL. I think this might be overkill for your scenario, but it is better if you have difficulty coming up with a safe delimiter.

### 3. Use Table-Valued Parameters

This one is probably WAY overkill, but you can write a stored procedure to take in a [user-defined Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) which is a type you define in SQL that looks to SQL just like a table. You can load it up with your data in C# and pass it to the procedure. I have to admit, it's been a long time since I messed with TVPs so I don't know the syntax for that in C# right now, but it is an option.

### Help with a SQL Routine

If you can provide some information about the format of the tokens, and some examples, we may be able to help extract the date component from the token using SQL. However I would recommend creating a new question for that.